# node.js and express passing sqlite data to one of my views

Tags: node.js, express

In my app.js I have the following to try to retrieve data from a sqlite database and pass it to one of my views:

```
app.get("/dynamic", function(req, res) {
    var db = new sqlite3.Database(mainDatabase)
    var posts = []

    db.serialize(function() {
        db.each("SELECT * FROM blog_posts", function(err, row) {
            posts.push({title: row.post_title, date: row.post_date, text: row.post_text})
        })
    })

    res.render("dynamic", {title: "Dynamic", posts: posts})
})
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here.  The posts array seems to stay empty nomatter what.

**EDIT**
I was following a [tutorial](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-sqlite) that explained that though the plugin has async, this method is not asynchronous

Here is a quote from the tutorial

> Despite the callbacks and asynchronous nature of Node.js, these
>   transactions will run in series, allowing us to create, insert, and
>   query knowing that the statement prior will run before the current one
>   does. However, sqlite3 provides a "parallel" wrapper with the same
>   interface, but runs all the transactions in parallel. It just all
>   depends on your current circumstances.

Comment: Regarding your edit: `serialize != synchronous`. `serialize` just places the queries in a queue and delays the start of each until the previous query has completed. So, you can count on them occurring in order rather than in parallel/all-at-once, but each query still executes asynchronously.

Comment: Thankyou for clearing that up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the `db` calls are likely asynchronous.  Which means you are rendering before they return with their data.

You need to figure out how to get one callback from your query, and render your template in that callback.

It looks like you want a second `complete` callback passed to [`db.each()`](https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete) (Thanks, [Jonathan Lonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski), for the tip!)

```
var posts = [];
db.serialize(function() {
    db.each("SELECT * FROM blog_posts", function(err, row) {
        posts.push({title: row.post_title, date: row.post_date, text: row.post_text})
    }, function() {
        // All done fetching records, render response
        res.render("dynamic", {title: "Dynamic", posts: posts})
    })
})
```

The idea is the render in the last callback of any asynchronous code, that way you have everything you need.

---

Comment: I thought at first it might be something to do with it being asynchronous and it probably is.  I just thought this would work because doing

`console.log(row.post_title+" "+row.post_text+" "+row.post_date)`

will print the info perfectly fine in the console

Comment: @CarsonEvans Yeah but that `console.log()` call would happen _after_ the page was rendered.  In your original code, `res.render()` is called, then after that the db query returns a result.

Comment: Thankyou so much!! It worked.  I am going to have to remember this i nthe future as I do more.

Comment: Two things: 1 - Why do you use serialize? Its only applicable for updates / inserts. 2 - Use the all method instead of each. It returns an array of all rows, and saves you the trouble.
As i see it, one should use some kind of async rendering, to optimize this, but thats a hole different story.