# Trying to understand how to incorporate a callback into Node.js/SQLITE

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm pretty new to all this and am struggling to figure out how to control the order of operations in my node code. When I load the page, my variables say 'undefined' until I refresh the browser a second time. I am assuming this is because the Jade/Pug page is being rendered before the db query. Everything I have read suggests that I need to control the order using callbacks, but I can't seem to get it working. This is my pre-butchered code.

```
exports.count = function(req, res) {

    //Get in count
    db.all("SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM tableName WHERE status='in'",
      function(err, rows){
        inCount=rows[0].cnt;
        console.log("Items In: " + inCount);
    });

    //Get out count
    db.all("SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM tableName WHERE status='out'",
      function(err, rows){
        outCount=rows[0].cnt;
        console.log("Items Out: " + outCount);
    });

    //Render Count to Pug view
    res.render('count', { _incount: inCount + ' in', _outcount: outCount + ' out'});

};
```

This is what I was trying to follow, but it causes my page to time out.
[node.js and express passing sqlite data to one of my views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954743/node-js-and-express-passing-sqlite-data-to-one-of-my-views)

Any help would be most appreciated, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module for managing asynchronous control flow - like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) - can help you with this. If you need an introduction to async, there is a blog post [here](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice) that you might find useful.

For example:

```
exports.count = function(req, res) {

  async.series([
    function (callback) {

      //Get in count
      db.get("SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM tableName WHERE status='in'", callback);
    },
    function (callback) {

      //Get out count
      db.get("SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM tableName WHERE status='out'", callback);
    }
  ], function (error, results) {

    if (error) {
      // ... handle the error in an appropriate manner
    } else {
      res.render('count', { _incount: results[0].cnt + ' in', _outcount: results[1].cnt + ' out'});
    }
  }
};
```

Also, `get` would be more appropriate for the queries that you are making in your example, as there will only be a single row in each result.

Comment: Thanks for the code and blog post. These were really helpful. I think the results came back as an object. I was getting [object Object] in the HTML, so I sent it to the console and saw that it was printing { cnt: 2 }. 

I spent a while trying to figure out how to get stuff out of an object and eventually tried adding .cnt after results[0], and it worked! Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Sorry, typed the example up from memory. I've edited the code in my answer.